# pointers in the IAR compiler

Tags: c++, c, pointers, iar

Long story short I have this in C using the IAR EWARM compiler.

```
uint8_t packet[2048];
uint32_t* src = (uint32_t*)&packet[9];
uint32_t var = *src++;
```

That last line causes a bus fault.

```
uint8_t packet[2048];
uint32_t* src = (uint32_t*)&packet[9];
uint32_t var = 0xFE;
*src++;
```

Now there is no bus fault. I can see in the debugger src points to the data I expect it to point to. Increment it works as expected but trying to read it casues a bus fault.

Any help?

Comment: It's an assembly of random chunks of information. Insufficient not only for answering, but even for understanding what was asked.

Comment: Seems clear to me. You have a prototype of my function, you can see how I reference the pointer as I pass it in. You have the actual call to the function. And you have the actual line in the function where the error happened along with the actual error.

Comment: Just FYI - there are 3 close votes as unclear at the moment.

Comment: Worth a shot, thanks for the help!

Comment: @lusher00 it would be better to tag according to which language you are using; C and C++ are different

Comment: bus errors are caused by alignment problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that your MCU needs reads of 32 bit integers to be aligned to 32 bits.

`&packet[9]` is most certainly not 32 bit aligned, that's why you get a fault.

Comment: Yup, that's it. I forgot all about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`&packet[9]` is probably not aligned correctly for `uint32_t`.  Seeing "Bus Error" on an ARM CPU is often a sign of an alignment error. [See here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/) for an explanation of alignment.

On the second example it probably avoids the bus fault by optimizing out the `*` operation, since you never use the result.

Note that even if you fix this, the code still causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule.  (`uint8_t` may not be aliased as `uint32_t`).  Some compilers may appear to "work correctly" for now but the code could break at any time in future.

The safe equivalent of your code would be:

```
uint8_t *src = &packet[9];
uint32_t var;
memcpy(&var, src, sizeof var);
src += sizeof var;
```

Note that if the source data is specified as having a particular byte order for integer (e.g. you are getting it from network stream as opposed to data you saved earlier by the same method) then you will want to use a method to read the data that is independent of the  representation of `uint32_t`.  (In other words, "endianness").